# Angular directive with ng-if inside another ng-if not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-if

Here is the directive:

```
<a ng-if="field.bindingType == 'options'">
 <select ng-model="field.value" {{html}} >
  <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in field.options" value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
 </select>
</a>
<a ng-if="field.bindingType != 'options'">
 <a ng-if="['text','ntext','nvarchar','varchar'].indexOf(field.type) > -1">
  <textarea ng-model="field.value" {{html}} ></textarea>
 </a>
 <a ng-if="['double','float','int'].indexOf(field.type) > -1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="field.value" {{html}} />
 </a>
 <a ng-if="field.type == 'bit'">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.value" {{html}} />
 </a>
 <a ng-if="field.type == 'date'">
  <input type="date" ng-model="field.value" {{html}} />
 </a>
 <a ng-if="field.type == 'time'">
  <input type="time" ng-model="field.value" {{html}} />
 </a>
 <a ng-if="field.type == 'datetime'">
  <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="field.value" {{html}} />
 </a>
</a>
```

For some reason, when *field.bindingType* is 'options', and therefore passes the first **ng-if**, it can still pass the second **ng-if** (bindingType is NOT 'options'). Obviously, that's not possible, but it keeps happening.

This only happens when field. type matches one of the inner ng-if conditions, though. It's as if it is ignoring the *ng-if="field.bindingType != 'options'"* part of the directive.

What's the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: huff difficult to read.. Why dont you use template url or worst case you dont have to concat string in js to be able to continue in the next line you can add [multi-line string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Multi-line_strings) in javascript with **`\\`**

Comment: @PSL I cleared up the formatting.

Comment: Can you put this in a jsFiddle?  Now it looks like you're missing a bunch of quotes.  You probably mean ng-if="field.bindingType == 'options'" with quotes, right?

Comment: @DanCaddigan Added quotes. I would have to make a mock-up of the whole thing for a jsfiddle. The actual code is thousands of lines.

Comment: Sounds like some tags aren't getting closed.  I would inspect the generated markup and make sure your original <a> tag is getting closed.

Comment: @DanCaddigan yeah it looks like Angular isn't closing the tags, but they are closed in the template so obviously that's Angular's problem not mine and really doesn't help solve the problem.

Comment: @KthProg either that or your {{html}} is doing something bad.   Can you remove the {{html}} to make your example simpler?  Any way you could get an example in a jsfiddle?  You're way more likely to get your issues resolved with a jsfiddle or a plnkr.

Comment: Someone resurrected this and edited it? lol. Man I hardly remember what I was even working on back then.